# Oracle users tablespace has high allocated memory but not used, possible cause?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, tablespace

On my development environment I have Oracle 10G XE installation.

I often run scripts which contains a lot of Stored Procedure definitions. 
It may happen that I submit CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE xxxxxxxxxxxx for hundreds of Stored Procedures many times a day.

Can this cause a rapid increase of memory allocation of the tablespace keeping the usage low?

The problem is that once in a while Oracle will refuse to compile new Stored Procedures issuing a "ORA-12952: The request exceeds the maximum allowed database size of 4 GB"

I have to issue a compact storage command (through the Oracle Web interface) to free up some space in order to keep redefining my stored procedures.

I have the following:

```
TABLESPACE_NAME                TOTAL_BYTES USED_BYTES FREE_BYTES
------------------------------ ----------- ---------- ----------
SYSAUX                           461373440  461307904            
USERS                           4414504960   32702464 4386127872 
SYSTEM                           356515840  355991552     458752 
UNDO                             524288000   10354688  513867776
```

As you can see the USERS tablespace has 4GB of allocated memory, but the usage is under 20MBs.

Is there any typical reason for this behavior (high allocation/low usage)? 
Can I do something to avoid this?

This is the script I used for getting the statistics:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) AS total_bytes
    FROM dba_data_files
    GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, sum(bytes) AS used_bytes
    from dba_segments
    GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) AS free_bytes
    FROM dba_free_space
    GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to worry about the tablespace usage. Most of the storage is consumed by table data not by procedure, function, triggers or packages. Monitor tablespace usage as your table data grows.

Comment: Do you find my answer as useful? Please vote up if yes.